# To make your personal enemy or rival

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, semantics

I'm watching the GOP debate, and I'm noticing that some candidates are picking on Hillary.

Is there a verb for an act where a person castigates someone else in hopes of making that person his or her personal rival or enemy?

Comment: I'm under the impression candidates were mudslinging. More details of the conversation would make for a clearer question.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like *baiting*. *American Heritage Dictionary* defines *[bait](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=bait)* as

> To entice or provoke, especially by trickery or strategy: *He baited me into selling him my bike by saying how much I deserved a better one.*

Answer (score 1):

[**Alienate**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alienate):

> to make (someone) unfriendly : to cause (someone) to stop being friendly, helpful, etc., towards you

Or similarly, [**estrange**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/estrange):

> to cause someone to be no longer friendly or close to another person or group

These words typically indicate that at least a cordial relationship existed previously, but actions are taken to cause that relationship to cease.

Comment: Estrange is a near perfect word for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Both "challenge" or "call out" fit your case extremely well; Both can be used to refer to a call to a fight, figuratively or literally. "Singled out" or "gunning for" have some of the same connotations, too.

If you're on the hunt for a term with negative denotations or connotations, you could lean more towards "bully", "sniped", or "picked a fight with".

Something along the lines of "declaim" would also fit, but has no rivalrous aspect to it.

Answer (score 1):

You could say, *some candidates **were riding roughshod over** (or **dumping on**) Hillary*.

> ride (or *run* or *roll*) roughshod over someone: to treat someone roughly or without care, respect, moderation, or control; to act in a bullying manner toward someone [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/ride_roughshod_over)
>
> dump on someone: criticize someone severely and unfairly [The Amercan Heritage Dictionary of Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/dump)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like **provoking**, with meaning defined by M-W under "to provoke":

> : to cause (a person or animal) to become angry, violent, etc.

Answer (score 0):

"[***Antagonize***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/antagonize)" is broadly used in that context which means:

> Cause (someone) to become hostile:'It is spending astronomical amounts
>   of money, alienating allies and further ***antagonizing*** opponents.'

Or you could consider using "[***make an enemy of***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/make-an-enemy-of)".

> Cause (someone) to start feeling hostile to one: 'you really don’t want
>   to ***make an enemy of*** your girlfriend’s best mate'

[Oxford Online Dictionary]